# Sprite animation left to right, what should I choose? Dynamic or Kinematic?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I'm trying to make an animation with a Sprite image. The animation is a character that moves from left to right of the screen and then right to left non-stop (loop). How do I go about doing it? Should I assign the physics of the character (actor) dynamic or kinematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a dynamic body is controlled via forces, whereas with a kinematic body you assign positions directly. Therefore a kinematic body is more what you want. The question then becomes whether you need collision detection for this character.

Calculating the position of a character moving right-left can be done like:

```
float x = t % (2 * width);
if (x > width) x = 2 * width - x;
```

Where `t` is the output of `System.currentTimeMillis` or equivalent. Or you could use TweenEngine for the same effect. The sprite can then be drawn like following:

```
sprite.setX(x);
sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
```

Comment: One point to bear in mind is that in Libgdx, using box2d, a kinematic body can have a velocity as well not  by setting the position which isn't recommended for physics games.  Also, kinematic bodies still allow for collision detection but do not react to any forces